# convert nchar(20) field to a datetime data type in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to select from a table and filter on dates greater than a 
specified date.

The problem I'm having is that the dates are stored as nchar(20) and I 
can't seem to get it converted to date in the where clause.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,log_time,20) from dbo.logs 
where CONVERT(DATETIME,log_time,20) > '10/20/2008'
```

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Comment: Show us the format of how you're storing the datetime so we can show you how to convert the varchar into datetime.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
select convert(datetime, cast(rtrim(log_time), nvarchar)) from dbo.logs
where convert(datetime, cast(rtrim(log_time), nvarchar)) > '10/20/2008'
```

Answer (score 1):

I talked to our SQL Server DBA.  He said the problem was with bad data.  He said on some the dates the m was left off of the am or pm.  He wrote me a view where he handles the problem for me and now I can select from the view and the date is a datetime data type also.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Billy

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select convert(datetime, cast(trim(log_time), nvarchar)) from dbo.logs
where convert(datetime, cast(trim(log_time), nvarchar)) > '10/20/2008'
```

I think the trick is that you need to trim the string and cast to nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'trim' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 0):

Msg 1035, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'cast', expected 'AS'.

Answer (score 0):

Try

select convert(datetime, cast(rtrim(log_time) AS nvarchar)) from dbo.logswhere convert(datetime, cast(rtrim(log_time) AS nvarchar)) > '10/20/2008'

or simply

select CAST(log_time AS DATETIME) from dbo.logs
where CAST(log_time AS DATETIME) > '10/20/2008'